# How to run PuTTY serial commands in Python/ PySerial

Tags: python, putty, pyserial, com-port

I'm trying to communicate with probe by serial COM port. Manufacturer make some commands in PuTTY ec. change measurement units or read some values. I write peace of code in python but I received nothing or I don't know what I recieved. Here is PuTTY configuration

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Next is example of commands from  manufacturer for PuTTY.

[image: 4]

Here is code in PuTTY terminal:

[image: 5]

My code in Python:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = 'COM5'
ser.baudrate = 19200
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
ser.xonxoff = 0
ser.rtscts = 0
ser.dsrdtr = 0
ser.stopbits = 1
ser.timeout = 1
ser.open()

if ser.isOpen():
    print(ser.name + ' is open...')
    while True:
        cmd = input("Enter command or 'exit':")
        if cmd == 'exit':
            ser.close()
            break
        else:
            # ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
            # ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
            ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n')) #
            out = ser.readline().decode("utf-8").strip()
            print('Receiving... ' + str(out))
```

And here is what I received:

```
Enter command or 'exit':UNIT
Receiving...
Enter command or 'exit':exit
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
you can pass in a timeout value to your serial instance. Try increasing this although i don't think thats the problem here. More likely the device your communicating with doesn't send newline / carriage return characters at the end of it's messages. In that case you'd have to use `read()`. But you should be able to check what characters are sent by the device by checking a box that says something like `display newline characters` or `display CR/LF`. I'm not sure if putty supports this, since i don't really use it as a serial monitor, but it probably does.